# Your funniest Baal Teshuva stories

Tags: baal-teshuva, humor

For those of us who weren't born into religious households, it's a very emotional and often gut-wrenching process making the transition to a religious lifestyle and world-view.  At the same time a lot of very funny situations can arise from the dichotomy involved in this process.

As a way of supporting each other through the process of becoming more Jewishly involved, I invite you to share some of your funnier moments in your baal teshuva experience!

Comment: A great book full of Baal Teshuva stories: "Kiruv Files", by R' Dovid Kaplan.

Comment: There is of course the famous joke: Q. How many baalei teshuvah does it take to change a lightbulb? A. Are we allowed to?

Comment: @Alex - while you're at it, you know about the 2 baalei teshuva on a shidduch-date?  They were named Baskah and Kelikaku!

Comment: Stack Exchange sites are not traditional forums - these are Q&A sites.  Please read the [faq](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq), the [how to ask](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) page, and the [how to ask beta](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask-beta) page for lots of details and links in the sidebar to recommended blog entries.  A question like this doesn't work well here.

Answer (score 5):

There is a story about the Gerrer Rebbe, when a fellow came to visit him. The Rebbe asked him "where are you learning"?, and he said "in Ohr Sameach, however I am not a Baal Teshuva". The Rebbe said "Why not"?

Comment: I like this story.  It reminds us that each of us should try to be a Baal Teshuva in the literal sense of the phrase.

Answer (score 4):

I'll kick off with one of my experiences...

One of the first times I went to a religious family for a shabbos meal, at the end of the meal they brought out the mayim acharonim.  They didn't have a special mayim acharonim set; they just served it in a teacup.  Being the guest, they put it in front of me first.  I had no idea what this all meant, and I was looking around for cues, but the parents were busy with the children and not catching my "what is this?" look... so I drank it.

No, the baal habayis didn't drink some more after me; I don't think he noticed.  But I was very entertained to hear that famous story subsequently, and couldn't resist saying - "Hey!  That was **me**!"  :)